# Pandas return columns for one dataframe based on multple columns from another

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched for an answer to this problem but I don't even know how to describe it in a way that is bring up approximate results.

Situation:

I would like to bring the value columns in df and merge them into df2, but i need to merge on multiple columns depending on it returns a value or not. The process today is to see if values are returned by joining on the HIGH, MID, then LOW columns, in that order depending on if a value is returned or not.  You would only join on the MID column if some of the HIGH values didn't return a result, then you would do the same process with the LOW column if there were still no matches.  I was looking into the groupby method, but don't know if this is the best way to achieve my goal.

Here is a basic example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'LOW' : ['Abc', 'Bcd', 'CdE'], 'MID' : ['aBc', 'bCd', 'cDe'], 'HIGH': ['abC', 'bcD', 'cdE'], 'VALUE1': ['1','2','3'], 'VALUE2': ['bb','dd','ee']})

df

+----+-------+------+------+---------+--------+
|    | HIGH  | LOW  | MID  | VALUE1  | VALUE2 |
+----+-------+------+------+---------+--------+
| 0  | abC   | Abc  | aBc  |      1  | bb     |
| 1  | bcD   | Bcd  | bCd  |      2  | dd     |
| 2  | cdE   | CdE  | cDe  |      3  | ee     |
+----+-------+------+------+---------+--------+   

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'LOW' : ['Abc-4', 'Bcd-1', 'CdE'], 'MID' : ['aBc*2', 'bCd', 'cDe&3'], 'HIGH': ['abC', 'bcD$22', 'cdE#2']})

df2

+----+---------+--------+-------+
|    |  HIGH   |  LOW   |  MID  |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| 0  | abC     | Abc-4  | aBc*2 |
| 1  | bcD$22  | Bcd-1  | bCd   |
| 2  | cdE#2   | CdE    | cDe&3 |
+----+---------+--------+-------+

df_result

+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    |  HIGH   |  LOW   |  MID   | VALUE  | VALUE2 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 0  | abC     | Abc-4  | aBc*2  |     1  | bb     |
| 1  | bcD$22  | Bcd-1  | bCd    |     2  | dd     |
| 2  | cdE#2   | CdE    | cDe&3  |     3  | ee     |
+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: i think only way here is to first merge on `HIGH`, check for `nan`, if `nan`s present then merge on next and so on.

Comment: I ended up going with this suggestion.  The answer below works perfectly for my simple example, but it didn't for my actual use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better example would help, but if I am following correctly, the following works:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df, on='HIGH', how='inner', suffixes=['', 'r'])
df4 = pd.merge(df2, df, on='MID', how='inner', suffixes=['', 'r'])
df5 = pd.merge(df2, df, on='LOW', how='inner', suffixes=['', 'r'])
df6 = pd.concat([df3, df4, df5]).drop(['HIGHr', 'MIDr', 'LOWr'], axis=1)

df6

    HIGH    LOW     MID     VALUE1  VALUE2
0   abC     Abc-4   aBc*2   1       bb
1   bcD$22  Bcd-1   bCd     2       dd
2   cdE#2   CdE     cDe&3   3       ee
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'LOW' : ['Abc', 'Bcd', 'CdE'], 'MID' : ['aBc', 'bCd', 'cDe'], 'HIGH': ['abC', 'bcD', 'cdE'], 'VALUE1': ['1','2','3'], 'VALUE2': ['bb','dd','ee']})
df1=df.drop(['VALUE1','VALUE2'],axis=1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'LOW' : ['Abc-4', 'Bcd-1', 'CdE'], 'MID' : ['aBc*2', 'bCd23', 'cDe&3'], 'HIGH': ['abC', 'bcD$22', 'cdE#2']})

rowsum=numpy.sum((df1==df2).astype(int),axis=1)
df_result=df2
df_result['VALUE1']=df.VALUE1*rowsum
df_result['VALUE2']=df.VALUE2*rowsum
df_result

Out[4]: 
     HIGH    LOW    MID VALUE1 VALUE2
0     abC  Abc-4  aBc*2      1     bb
1  bcD$22  Bcd-1  bCd23              
2   cdE#2    CdE  cDe&3      3     ee
```